# What population(s) are assumed to be normal when we perform hypothesis testing of difference of means and have small samples?

Tags: self-study, interpretation

I have following problem from my textbook that confused me with its assumption.
[image]

We have 5 populations:

1.The (orignal) population of "Fast music"

2.The population of samples from population #1 (i.e. sampling population of #1)

3.The original population of "Slow music"

4.The sampling population of #3 population

5.The original population of difference of sample means from populations #2 and #4.

The highlighted text says "population" instead of "populations", so theoretically it should indicate the population #5. BUT, I already caught my textbook with not caring about accurate plurals. Namely, later in the text it shows how to do hypothesis testing of the difference between means when "the sigma is unknown". It uses as an example situation when I don't know population standard deviation for either sample. But in this case it's more correct to say "the sigmas unknown", instead of "the sigma unknown". It gives space for reasonable doubt that maybe my textbook didn't actually mean ONE population, but TWO.

If the textbook meant two populations, then it most likely meant populations #1 and #3.It seems plausible, given that their corresponding samples are less than 30, thus parent populations need to be normal in order for their sampling populations to be normal.

On the other hand, if the textbook really meant the population #5, then how do we generally know that such assumption holds true? I mean in this example it would be given as true, but I doubt that I will have such privelege in the real life.This makes me doubt that it's what the textbook meant.

Comment: (1) The textbook should have more clearly said that *each* population has a normal distribution.  That interpretation is forced on us by the fact it has stipulated two different population SDs. (2) Ordinarily one does not refer to samples as "populations" because the proliferation of "populations" becomes confusing.

Comment: @whuber About (2), where did I refer to samples as populations? I never meant it this way.

Comment: If you didn't mean it this way, then what *did* you mean by the phrases "The population of samples from" and "The original population of difference of sample means"?  The first phrase has a conventional meaning but, in the context of a *single* sample, looks out of place.  The meaning of the second phrase is unclear.

Comment: @whuber "but, in the context of a single sample, looks out of place" Ah, I see, you mean there is no populations of samples. We take a sample as a sample, not a sample as an element of a population. Did I understnad you correctly? "The original population of difference of sample means". We take one random sample from the first sampling population and find its mean. Then we take one random sample from the second sampling population and find its mean. Then we find difference of their means. If we repeat it we will have population of differences. Is it clear now?

Comment: Yes--I figured you probably meant something like that.  But none of this seems germane to the textbook question.